# Difference between HTTPServletResponse and a ResponseEntity(Spring)?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a website using Spring for the first time, and I am trying to understand how to use it best. I noticed that some programmers/tutorials will use a ResponseEntity<> for some responses, and others use the HttpServletResponse. 
Is there a difference between the two classes/responses? Which one would be recommended to use when I am trying to work with setting cookies. 
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to set a cookie on the response, you are probably better off using `HTTPServletResponse`.  That will give you access to the full servlet API and features such as setting cookies.  ResponseEntity is a higher level Spring abstraction which works great in the normal case (handling AJAX requests), but HttpServletReponse is a "standard" which give full low-level access to the full http response object.

Answer (score 3):

`ResponseEntity` is a Spring-specific class used within a `@Controller` annotated class to tell Spring what to send back as the body of response to a request.  `HttpServletResponse` is a standard Java class that represents the entire response, including headers and a bunch of other stuff.  These two objects perform different functions, although either can be used as part of returning a response to a HTTP request.

As you've seen different uses of these two classes, you should look at those uses and understand them.   Then you could see how they each serve a different function in returning a HTTP response.  I could also serve you well to read the documentation for each class, and possibly look at the documentation for the superclass chain for each object.